# Generating dynamic sql filter script in effective way

Tags: php

I am writing the following code listed below to generate query filter script dynamically based on various values. In some cases these values are few, but in some cases it goes beyond limit which looks my code structure very conjusted.

Here is sample filter query generation code.

```
if ($entity->iscomments != 2)
    {
        $script .= " v.iscomments=:iscomments";
        if ($entity->term != "" || $entity->categoryid != 0 || $entity->isfeatured != 3 || $entity->type != 2 || $entity->username != "" || $entity->month > 0 || $entity->isenabled != 2 || $entity->isapproved != 2 || $entity->isadult != 2 || $entity->isprivate != 3 || $entity->isexternal != 3 || $entity->datefilter > 0 || $entity->filter > 0 || $entity->mode > 0 || $entity->galleryid > 0)
            $script .= " AND";
    }
    if ($entity->galleryid > 0)
    {
        $script .= " v.galleryid=:galleryid";
        if ($entity->term != "" || $entity->categoryid != 0 || $entity->isfeatured != 3 || $entity->type != 2 || $entity->username != "" || $entity->month > 0 || $entity->isenabled != 2 || $entity->isapproved != 2 || $entity->isadult != 2 || $entity->isprivate != 3 || $entity->isexternal != 3 || $entity->datefilter > 0 || $entity->mode > 0)
            $script .= " AND";
    }

    if ($entity->isprivate != 3)
    {
        $script .= " v.isprivate=:isprivate";
        if ($entity->term != "" || $entity->categoryid != 0 || $entity->isfeatured != 3 || $entity->type != 2 || $entity->username != "" || $entity->month > 0 || $entity->isenabled != 2 || $entity->isapproved != 2 || $entity->isadult != 2 || $entity->isexternal != 3 || $entity->datefilter > 0 || $entity->mode > 0)
            $script .= " AND";
    }

    if ($entity->mode > 0)
    {
        $script .= " v.mode=:mode";
        if ($entity->term != "" || $entity->categoryid != 0 || $entity->isfeatured != 3 || $entity->type != 2 || $entity->username != "" || $entity->month > 0 || $entity->isenabled != 2 || $entity->isapproved != 2 || $entity->isadult != 2 || $entity->isexternal != 3 || $entity->datefilter > 0)
            $script .= " AND";
    }
    if ($entity->categoryid != 0)
    {
        $script .= " v.categoryid=:categoryid";
        if ($entity->term != "" || $entity->isfeatured != 3 || $entity->type != 2 || $entity->username != "" || $entity->month > 0 || $entity->isenabled != 2 || $entity->isapproved != 2 || $entity->isadult != 2 || $entity->isexternal != 3 || $entity->datefilter > 0)
            $script .= " AND";
    }
```

In code it look like huge no of if conditions, which make code conjested and not looking well but it works perfectly.

Is there any better approach to cope with such situation in order to generate complex filter queries but using less amount of code and with better way.

Comment: I don't understand the inner big if statements. Shouldn't there always be an `AND` but not at the end of the query?

Comment: Inner if condition check whether there in other filter active if yes then it append AND before it.

Comment: another approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351617/build-dynamic-sql-with-and-expressions-without-confusing-nested-conditionals/14351748#14351748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$filters = array();

if ($entity->iscomments != 2) {
    $filters[] = "v.iscomments=:iscomments";
}

if ($entity->galleryid > 0) {
    $filters[] = "v.galleryid=:galleryid";
}

...

$script .= ' '.implode(' AND ', $filters);
```

Comment: thanks, it looks to work. i am implementing and let u update.

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly and made code much much cleaner and better